# Old to new website TLD rewrite rule with apache

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I need to redirect the following URLs:

```
https://testing.co.uk/kilts/      -> https://www.example.co.uk/kilts/
https://www.testing.co.uk/kilts/  -> https://www.example.co.uk/kilts/
http://testing.co.uk/kilts/       -> https://www.example.co.uk/kilts/
https://www.testing.co.uk/kilts/  -> https://www.example.co.uk/kilts/
https://www.testing.co.uk/assets/downloads/files/2021.pdf -> https://www.example.co.uk/assets/downloads/files/2021.pdf
```

So essentially testing.co.uk -> example.co.uk

I can currently have the following rule:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)testing\.co\.uk$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.example.co.uk/$1 [L,R=301]
```

All URLs appear to work, however it is breaking when the application calls a curl request. Not sure why yet, but I was wondering if I could try a more explicit rewrite rule.

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^testing\.co\.uk$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.testing\.co\.uk$ [NC]
RewriteRule (.*)$ https://www.example.co.uk/$1 [R=301,L]
```

But if I try testing.co.uk it won't pass the 2nd rule and then never rewrites.

Update:

The following redirect rule was working with the curl task but not www

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^testing\.co\.uk$ [NC]
RewriteRule $ https://www.example.co.uk/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: Make `www` optional by using `RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:www\.)?testing\.co\.uk$ [NC]` and test from `curl`

Comment: _"however it is breaking when the application calls a curl request"_ - a POST request? That probably gets followed up with a GET request, when status code 301 is received - which means you'd lose any POST data at this point. Maybe try 307/308 instead.

Comment: @anubhava thanks I tried that but the curl is still breaking. I have added a previous rule that was working with the curl task.

Comment: @CBroe thanks, I will have a look into this

Comment: @xylar: Can you show full output of `curl -I 'https://www.testing.co.uk/kilts/'` in your question